# Laravel Nova: Convert Datetime to readable output

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

Is there an option in Laravel Nova to display an readable date-time output and/or limit the output?

**For example to :** 29. October 2018 / 11. November 2018, 12:10 am

[image: Datetime]

**Code:**

```
   DateTime::make('Start')
                ->rules('required')
                ->sortable(),
```

Comment: show your blade code instead of an image

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is achieved in **Nova 4.0+** with the `displayUsing` method:

```php
DateTime::make('Updated', 'updated_at')
->displayUsing(fn ($value) => $value ? $value->format('D d/m/Y, g:ia') : '')
```

Answer (score 11):

As per documentation https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#datetime-field

```
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\DateTime;

DateTime::make('Start')->format('DD MMMM YYYY'),
```

Must use Moment.js formatting rules https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Does not work in laravel nova 4.*

Answer (score 3):

use this, hope it will works

```
Date::make('start')->format('F j, Y'),
```

Comment: This is not working on `Laravel Nova 4.*`

Comment: See my answer above for Nova 4.*

Answer (score 0):

We also faced such a problem.
This solution DateTime::make('Start')->format('DD MMMM YYYY'), helps only for index page, but didn't help for Edit page.
I don't know when this bug will be fixed in new Nova releases but we temporary used small hardcoding.

- 1. nova/src/Fields/Date.php

```
 instead: return $value->format('Y-m-d');
 use this one: return $value->format('m/d/Y');
```

- 2. nova/resources/js/components/Form/DateField.vue

```
 In this vue component also should be changed a date format: dateFormat="m/d/Y".
```

- 3. nova/resources/js/components/Form/DateField.vue

```
 For placeholder method use this one:
     return this.field.placeholder || moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
Instead this:
     return this.field.placeholder || moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

- 4. Also You should use Mutator in Your App\Model class if you store data in the database in another format. Something like this:

```
    public function setLastUsedAttribute($value){
          $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $value);
          $this->attributes['last_used'] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```